# What is the parent after the child is 'appendedTo'

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When I attach an element loaded from an external html to a dynamically created element using:

```
$(this).appendTo('#newHost'); // newHost is dynamically created
```

and call it's `parent()` I get the the "old" parent; where the element I'm appending resided in the original loaded html

How do I refer to `#newHost` as that name will be dynamically generated and not always the same?

EDIT:
When I look at the dev inspector DOM tree I see:

```
<div id="newHost" style="position: ...">
    <img id="ph01" src=".../image01.jpg" style="position...">
</div>
```

`$(this)` in my case is the image, I am trying to retrieve `#newHost` without actually calling it by `ID` name so that I can access its properties

Comment: its not clear what your problem is

Answer (score 1):

Use it the other way around:

```
$('#newHost').append(this). ...
```

Comment: doing so will make `newHost` the parent?

Comment: @user3101259: the `$('#newHost')` instance will be what `.append()` returns